# Predict new data using new x values and polynomial regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, lm, predict

I need to find a high degree polynomial fit to a set of data, then use that relationship to predict y values given x values. Here is a simplified example of the premise of my problem. I must create a regression (we can just do 2nd degree here, but I need a technique that can handle polynomials of any degree), then predict new y values given new x values.

```
dfram <- data.frame('x'=c(1,2,3,4))
dfram$y <- c(1,4,9,16)

pred <- data.frame('x'=c(5,6))
# predict pred$y using n degree trend in dfram
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the skeleton:

```
dfram <- data.frame('x'=c(1,2,3,4))
dfram$y <- c(1,4,9,16)

pred <- data.frame('x'=c(5,6))
myFit <- lm(y ~ poly(x,2), data=dfram)

predict(myFit, pred)
 1  2 
25 36
```

You can change the degree of polynomial with poly() arguments.